# scroll embedded frames in vb6

Tags: vb6, scrollbar, frame

I'm trying to create a scrolling area. I'm doing this by creating a frame, in which are another frames and a scroll bar. The scroll bar should move the inner frames up and down.

However, the inner frames are not moved by the scroll bar but the outher frame is moved on the form when using the scroll bar.

For scrolling I use the following code:

```
Private Sub scrollFrame()
Dim ctl As Control
Dim myFrame As Frame

For Each ctl In Me.Controls

  If (TypeOf ctl Is Frame) Then
    ctl.Top = ctl.Top + oldPos - VScroll1.Value
  End If

Next

oldPos = VScroll1.Value
End Sub
```

I have checked what is in *Me*, so *Me* contains the form and therefor the outher frame is moved. But I don't know how I can get the inner frames. Is there a way to get the elements contained by a control or should I get the controls in a different way?

Comment: `Me` doesn't help you much here, since `Controls` is already in the current namespace of your Form module code.  I'm not sure why you see people doing this sort of thing so often.  If you use it there why not use `Me.VScroll1` and `Me.EverythingUnderTheSun`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me.Controls contains all the controls on the form, even if they are contained in the outer frame.  However, each control has a Container property.  You can inspect this to determine all elements contained by the outer frame.

```
   For Each ctl In Me.Controls
      If (TypeOf ctl Is Frame And ctl.Container.Name = "Frame1") Then
         ctl.Top = ctl.Top + oldPos - VScroll1.Value
      End If
   Next
```